# Laravel models relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, foreign-keys

so I'm working on this app where we have Users model, and users have different roles such as an editor, an admin, a supervisor, a reader...etc and we have another model let's call it Articles that should have a foreign key to refer to the admin and also another foreign key to refer to the reader. In this case both, the admin and the reader, are users but they have different roles how should i refer to them in my Article model? Should I put something like:

*user_admin_id*

*user_reader_id*

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Normally when you ask questions on stackoverflow you need to provide the code you used trying to solve the problem, your question feels a little sparse.

Comment: there's no code yet for this case, there's a (normal or boring) users table/model and an articles table/model. what is important to me is to understand the concept, hoiw to link the users table with the articles table when users have different roles.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same model for users and admins, which you should, you can easily create a relationship between the tables using Eloquent Relations (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

You should have a `roles` table, and a `user_roles` table in which you save all roles a user has. This way, you can use middleware to check if a user has the admin role, after which you can give him more privileges.

You shouldn't have to use two columns to link to the `users` table, since this would be bad practice in database design.